# How to extract first base64 code out of file?

Tags: sed, awk, base64

On Linux I'm having text files and each contains 1 or 2 base64 blocks of code. Following is part of the file and 1 base64 block.

> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>
> RGVhciBMdWlzLA0KICANCkdvb2QgbW9uaW5nIQ0KT3VyIEJhbmsgYWNjb3VudCBpcyB1bmRlcmdvaW5nIGF1ZGl0IGZvciB0aGUgZmlzY2FsIHllYXIgYXMgcmVxdWlyZWQgYnkgdGhlIGNoaW5hIGZvcmVpZ24gY3VycmVuY3kgY29udHJvbCBwb2xpY3kgYW5kIHRoZSBhY2NvdW50IHdpbGwgbm90IGJlIGF2YWlsYWJsZSB1bnRpbCB0aGUgQ2hpbmVzZSB0YXggYnVyZWF1cyBhcmUgc
>   2F0aXNmaWVkIHRoYXQgYWxsIGFwcGxpY2FibGUgdGF4ZXMgaGF2ZSBiZWVuIHBhaWQgdXAuIFBsZWFzZSBob2xkIHBheW1lbnQgc28gaSBjYW4gZnVybmlzaCB5b3Ugd2l0aCBvdXIgcmV2aXNlZCBiYW5raW5nIGluZm9ybWF0aW9uLiAgDQoNCiAgDQpCZXN0IHJlZ2FyZHMNCiANCkRhdmlk
>
> ------=_Part_143209_644876817.1451544132767--

Which command can I use to extract first base64 out of the file?

My aim is to decode output to be readable

---

Example file decode command: https://superuser.com/a/663397

Example phrase decode command: https://askubuntu.com/a/178546

I don't know how to extract only base64 part of code or if it contains two base64, only the first one. I may use `sed` or `awk`, but I don't know how I assume I will lookup for:

1. *base64*
2. *------=_Part_*

Trim the blank lines and I'm having base64 But what if there are 2 base64 sections? I want to have the first one.

Comment: If you mean picking apart a MIME multipart message, that is something your email client will do. Or you can cobble something up in Perl with MIME::Parser from [CPAN](http://www,cpan.org)

Comment: `grep -xm1 '^[[:alnum:] ]\{100,\}'`

Comment: It seems like all the 64bit-encoded data is one line. If that’s the case, I’d try to: (1) `grep` out all the lines containing headers, delimiters, and empty ones, then (2) take the first line with `head -1` and (3) pass it to `base64 -d`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I quite understand all of your question, but it seems that you have part of it figured out already and just need a way to trim out the text that you want to input into the `base64` command.

I want to answer this part:

> i assume i will lookup for a) base64 and b) ------=*Part*
>
> trim the blank lines and im having base64 but what if there are 2 base64, i want first one

You can print all the lines from the first instance of `base64` to the first-after-that instance of `=_Part_` with the following `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/base64/,${p;/=_Part_/q;}' inputfile
```

**Explanation:**

`-n` suppresses the default action of printing each line.

`/base64/,$` applies the following code block from the first instance of `base64` to the end of the file.  (`$` means last line in this context.)

`p` means to print the line.

`/=_Part_/` is a pattern which limits the `q` command that follows it so that it is only executed if the line contains `=_Part_`.

The `q` command quits `sed`, causing all subsequent lines to not be processed at all.

The upshot of all this is very *similar* to the simpler `sed -n '/base64/,/=_Part_/p' inputfile` which would print from `base64` to `=_Part_`—but this simpler version would print multiple such sections instead of stopping after the first.

Comment: true, but i think the comments above might also have it, too - its just a single line - base64 doesn't incorporate newlines anyway *(or so i think)*. so `sed -n '/base64/{n;n;p;q;}'` - maybe... but this is a more general solution overall.

Comment: @mikeserv, you could be right.  The example he posted isn't a single line (see `cmUgc`), but maybe it is a made-up example?  Anyway, for OP: explanation of mikeserv's line is just, when `base64` is first seen in the file, next line, next line, print *that* line, then quit.